# What are meta-stable states of Markov chain?

Tags: probability, markov-process

I frequently encounter this concept "meta-stable state" and "metastability" on some online materials about Markov Chain Monte Carlo but I don't know what it is. It feels like something similar to "local minimum" that the algorithm tries to escape. The textbook I have for Markov chain is a [math book](http://pages.uoregon.edu/dlevin/MARKOV/markovmixing.pdf) I cannot find this concept in it. Thanks!